Is there a way to keep the context of a context manager local to the as block?
I am trying to find a way to avoid having to create a bunch of names for some functions that I pass into another function.  I realize that if the functions were just simple expressions then I could just pass in lambdas and avoid creating named functions, but in many cases they are longer functions needing statements.
Here is an example of what I am doing. This approach works fine but requires me to define a unique named function and pass it into the subscribe function.
subscribers = []
def subscribe(handler):
    subscribers.append(handler)

def handler_1():
    print(f'handler 1')
subscribe(handler_1)

def handler_2():
    print(f'handler 2')
subscribe(handler_2)

for subscriber in subscribers:
    subscriber()

Running this yields the expected:
handler 1
handler 2

I was attempting to solve this by using a context manager.  Inside each width statement I was hoping to create a closure simply named handler and pass that to the subscribe function.  This does not work however since it seems the context variable is not local to the statements in the as block, but seems to be in the scope outside the with statement. The result is that each closure defined in each with / as statement captures the same context variable (from the last with statement.
Here is an example of what I was hoping my avoid creating a bunch of uniquely named functions.
from contextlib import contextmanager
@contextmanager
def foo(target):
    yield target

subscribers = []
with foo('target 1') as context:
    def handler():
        print(f'target = {context}')
        return context
    subscribe(handler)

with foo('target 2') as context:
    def handler():
        print(f'target = {context}')
        return context
    subscribe(handler)

for subscriber in subscribers:
    subscriber()

So the above code produces:
target = target 2
target = target 2

I guess in the end I was trying to used a context manager to implement something like a trailing closure,  but that does not seem possible if the context variable is not local.
Is there a way to avoid my original approach,  which works but requires a bunch of named functions,  which I feel might be error prone?

with statements do not create a new scope, which is what you appear to want to do.
As long as you aren't going to use the defined functions except via the references in subscribers, they don't need unique names. You don't even need to define subscribe explicitly; just decorate each identically named function with subscribers.append, and a reference to each newly defined function is saved to the list.
subscribers = []

@subscribers.append
def handler():
    print(f'handler 1')

@subscribers.append
def handler():
    print(f'handler 2')

for subscriber in subscribers:
    subscriber()

You can use a explicit closure to create a number of similar functions.
from contextlib import contextmanager


def make_handler(context):
    def handler():
        print(f'handler {context}')
    return handler

@contextmanager
def foo(target):
    yield target

subscribers = []
subscribers.append(make_handler(foo('target 1')))
subscribers.append(make_handler(foo('target 2')))

for subscriber in subscribers:
    subscriber()

The parameter context to make_handler exists only in the local scope of make_handler, and so each handler defined by a call to make_handler is a different context. The with statement does not create a new scope, so each use of context in your original example is the same variable in the current scope.

I want to associate each handler with a different object, then connect each object with its handler.  I am guessing I can still do that with a decorator scheme like you show in the first part of your answer?

I think I know what you are asking; let me modify my closure example to use your with example. The difference is/will be that make_handler creates a new scope where a with statement does not.

thanks,  will take a close look later this evening (not ignoring, just gotta mow the lawn :))

I used your first example as the inspiration for my solution.  I will post an answer showing exactly what I did when I am done.
